# Create a Google Task from a email

Tags: gmail, google-apps-script, task

I was looking the way to create a Task from an email at my Google Account with a filter. I've read this tutorial and it worked like a charm: http://www.pipetree.com/qmacro/blog/2011/10/automated-email-to-task-mechanism-with-google-apps-script/

The only bad thing is that the script creates a task with the subject of the message, and it's not really descriptive for me, because they are automatic messages, and all of them have the same subject. 
I want the Task Title be a specific line of the email body, can anybody helpme with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, basically you would get the message body and extract what you need from it. I'm not sure about the structure of your email but you need something in there that tells you the start and end of the task title, once you tell me what it is i can incorporate it in to the code. For now this is how you would set the body as the title.

```
var message     = thread.getMessages()[0]; // get first message
var messagebody = message.getBody(); 
var body_array  = messagebody.split('Sender:'); 
var taskTitle   = ''; 

if( body_array.length < 2 ) 
    taskTitle = 'No title specified in email after Sender:'; 
else 
{
    var text    = body_array[1]; 
    taskTitle   = text.split('<br />')[0].trim();  

}
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for your quick response! Can I get a line from some character to the end of the line? I mean something like this: "Sender: theguy@gmail.com", so I just want to get the text after "Sender: "

Comment: user, look at my edited code. This will get you everything after Sender:. And if they don't specify it then you can put a default message, i just put in no title specified for the time being.

Comment: Dude, that code is awesome!!! I have just only more question, If I want get the text between "Sender:" and "<br />", how can I do that? Im sorry of asking a lot, but Im not familiarized with java/javascript.

Comment: If it does please mark this as answered, helps me get some points :-)

Comment: It worked, but there's one problem...it works just for the first email, not for all messages with the "pending" label...do you know why?